# Compiler runs class outside build path instead of class inside build path

Tags: java, eclipse, buildpath

I'm developing a java application that uses a range a parallel projects. In one of the projects I have a class that is the implementation of an interface. A problem I'm having though is that this class seems to be represented in two ways, both as a class in the build path and as a class outside the build path.

In Eclipse I can have the class open as a tab with both "path-versions", one with a "filled in J" and one with a "hollow J". This isn't a problem for me, I don't care about that, the thing is though that the compiler always seem to run the class as the "not-being-part-of-the-build-path"-version. When I debug the debugger always ends up in the class outside the build path. This causes errors and the application crashes.

I have no idea how I should solve it. In my understanding this shouldn't even be a problem, the compiler should always run classes inside the build path, right..?

Does anyone have any idea of what the problem might be?

Here's the stack trace, though I don't think it will be of much use... =\

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.smarttrust.m2m.core.services.inventory.InventoryServiceImpl.getNetworks(InventoryServiceImpl.java:244) ~[m2m-core-services-1.0.0-A-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-A-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.smarttrust.m2m.ui.admin.inventory.InventoryAssignSubscription.populateDropdown(InventoryAssignSubscription.java:211) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.smarttrust.m2m.ui.admin.inventory.InventoryAssignSubscription.init(InventoryAssignSubscription.java:115) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.smarttrust.m2m.ui.admin.inventory.InventorySimCardTable$ActionColumnGenerator$1.buttonClick(InventorySimCardTable.java:352) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:490) ~[vaadin-6.6.3.jar:6.6.3]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

Comment: This kind of problem can happen if you use the Eclipse Maven plugin (m2e/m2eclipse) and a project POM depends on a version of the project that contains the problematic class that's different from the version you have in Eclipse

Comment: @NicolaMusatti You're probably right about that... My problem is that my main task with the project is developing the GUI for the application and the very high layered front-end parts. When it comes to problems like this that's happen at the very core of the project I'm at a loss... I'll probably have to wait till the next week to try and get a hold of someone else in my project group who can help me with it.. =\ Thanks anyway Nicola. =)

Answer (score 0):

Go to project build path, in `Order and Export` tab.
you see all source codes which is related to your project, You should move up the class that is right (as you say the one which is in build path)